# How to get the id of the button that created in repeater?And get it from Contentpageholder from MasterPage?Here is my Code

Tags: asp.net

I try this code in MasterPage but it did'nt work

```
     Button btn = Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("btnAddtoCart") as   Button;
  AsyncPostBackTrigger Trigger1 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    Trigger1.ControlID = btn.ID;
     Trigger1.EventName = "Click";
    UpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(Trigger1);
```

HTML code in ContentPage

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" >
  <ItemTemplate>
  <%# Eval("ProductName") %>
  <img width="150px" src="../Images/<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>" />
  <p><%# Eval("ProductDescription") %></p>
  <p><%# Eval("Price") %></p>
  <asp:Button ID="btnAddtoCart" runat="server" Text="AddtoCart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'OnClick="btnAddtoCart_Click" ></asp:Button> **strong text**
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line in `Onclick` event of the button and get the id

```
Button btn = (((sender as Button).Parent.Parent as Repeater).Items[((sender as Button).Parent as RepeaterItem).ItemIndex].FindControl("btnAddtoCart") as Button);
```

To get id of button separately :

```
Button btn = (Button)myRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("btnAddtoCart")
```